# How can I extend Module declarations exported from @types/node?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, .d.ts, typescript-declarations

`@types/node` doesn't offer types for private properties (prefixed with `_`) so I'd like to create a `.d.ts` file that types these properties:

- [Module#_compile](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d20e494d9fec1582c2ca5ff69730957e5af244b6/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L1111)
- [Module._extensions](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d20e494d9fec1582c2ca5ff69730957e5af244b6/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L173)
- [Module._resolveFilename](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d20e494d9fec1582c2ca5ff69730957e5af244b6/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L915)

The closest I have gotten is creating a `module.d.ts` like this:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface Module {
        _compile(code: string, filename: string): string;
    }
}

declare module 'module' {   
    const _extensions: NodeJS.RequireExtensions;
    export { _extensions };

    export function _resolveFilename(filename: string, module: any): string;
}
```

However, this conflicts with [`@types/node/module.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/36ef45c6684fc775e8b1f6906c5fb81c0e248434/types/node/module.d.ts#L109):

```
@types/node/module.d.ts:109:5 - error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.

109     export = Module;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `export const _extensions: NodeJS.RequireExtensions`?

Here is the completed code

```
// module.d.ts
import Module from "module";
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        export interface Module {
            _compile(code: string, filename: string): string;
        }
    }
}
declare module 'module' {
    export const _extensions: NodeJS.RequireExtensions
    export function _resolveFilename(filename: string, module: any): string;
}
```

Also I have tried your `_compile` declaration and it seems that it doesn't work without wrapping in `global` in my end.

Here is the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&moduleResolution=99&module=0#code/PTAEFsHsBMFcBsCmA6ayAuBnAsAKAJbgAOkATuqALIwKKgBmpk4oARFHEqwNx7SIBjeAENSdAObxIAI2HxQAbzygVoAHbDwiTEWEC6AORiIAUgGVFy1dcQAPEuVD416RKXp661TnSW5rAaoA%20gLMRPhIABSh-ABcoJjopM7iADQMEYgaWvGJyWriAJS5SSm8-oGgAL5WKjW49fxConQctKAA5G1IHZYVKnYOFKFqiaBBdq6j%20JCj8Ub85sgASogAjrD4YgCitlOYM6O1oINkFPSwagLoh%20NimJDwAG6IAGKZ2YiR9B%20aiCX5NIQGhIeLCNQAT2KCVKBXK9Tw3loyAmeyyB1mOFwIGsAD0APyIkEoIL3R4vd5IT54HGqAl4bok0LETI0sB0-FAA)